# How to sort a vector or deque KeyPair

Tags: c++, vector, int, deque, std-pair

I have a `deque <pair<int, int> > r;`.
I need to sort all by second parameter, and return a `deque<int>` of first all parameters.
For example:

```
deque<pair<int, int> > r;
r.push_back(make_pair(1, 5));
r.push_back(make_pair(0, 8));
r.push_back(make_pair(7, 3));
r.push_back(make_pair(2, 1));
```

I need this result

```
{2, 7, 1, 0}
```

I have a working method that "brute force" all value to N<sup>2</sup>, but it's very bad.
Maybe there exists something this `std::`? I hope you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define a comparison operator to work with the second item in your pair:

```
std::sort(r.begin(), r.end(), 
    [](std::pair<int, int> const &a, std::pair<int, int> const &b) {
         return a.second < b.second;
    }
);
```

...or, if you can't use a lambda (e.g., using too old of a compiler) you can define your functor explicitly instead:

```
template <class T>
struct by_second { 
    bool operator()(T const &a, T const &b) { 
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};

std::sort(r.begin(), r.end(), by_second());
```

From there, it's a matter of getting the first item in each pair and putting it into your result:

```
std::transform(r.begin(), r.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
    [](std::pair<int, int> const &p) { return p.first; });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) and provide your own comparator:

```
struct myclass {
    bool operator() (std::pair<int, int> i, std::pair<int, int> j) {
        return (i.second < j.second);
   }
} myobject;

std::sort(r.begin(), r.end(), myobject);
```

I haven't tried this with a `deque` in particular, but this is generally how this is done. The link has a more thorough example, though :-)